# Blown fuse on K1 GSXR 600. Fuse replaced, but still no power

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki, fuse, gsxr

I have a GSXR 600, and the live side of a circuit touched the frame and blew a 30A fuse. I changed the fuse and now I have no power. Does any one now why? Thanks

Comment: That may have not been the _only_ fuse, and just because the fuse blew doesn't mean something wasn't damaged a split second before.  Does the battery have voltage?  Are there other fuses?

Comment: What power is out, all of it, some of it, we really need more details in order to help you with this.

Comment: Any luck resolving this?

Comment: I have green neutral light on now nothing else no lights ect

Comment: Can you edit your question with all of the things you have tested and ruled out?  Where exactly is your 30 amp fuse located?

Answer (score 3):

**The thirty amp fuse is your main fuse**

To ensure we are speaking using the same nomenclature, K1 is referring to model year 2001 in my verbiage.

This 30 amp fuse supplies all the power to your fuse block with various 5, 10 and 20 amp fuses populated.

I have quite a few hours on this bike and have seen a scenario that you are describing.  Here are some recommendations.

- Check your 30 amp fuse for continuity with a multimeter.  Sometimes they come out of the box bad.  Rare but possible
- Check your starter circuit fuse under the seat.  When you say 'no power' does that mean headlights and everything or no power to turn the starter.  Is it a global 'lights out' across the board?
- Check all of your lower amperage fuses.  Some of them might have been taking out when the incident occurred.